Make the text start right after \addpart
I need to use \addpart for a large document, but I am not happy with the fact that there's a whole page left blank after the title. I would like the text to start right after the title, in the same page, like with \addchapter (but I can't really use \addchap in this case, since I need the two distinct levels part/chapter for the table of contents). I tried different things, as suppressing the vspace locally or in the preambule by renewing the command \addpart, but I don't seem to figure it out.
Here's a MWE illustrating the blank page I'd like to delete :
 \documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \addpart{Critique de la critique} 
    
    \lipsum[1-8]
    
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!

If you only need to add a preamble on the first part page, the scrbook class provides the \setpartpreamble command. Put \setpartpreamble{\lipsum[1-8]} before the `\part command (see KOMA-Script guide, section 3.16 Document Structure, p. 114).

You can use
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=chapter]{part}

Example:
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  style=chapter,
  afterskip=3\baselineskip plus .2\baselineskip minus .2\baselineskip,% example values
  beforeskip=5\baselineskip,% example value
  afterindent=false
]{part}

% to center the part title:
\newcommand\useraggedpart[1]{\let\raggedchapter\raggedpart}
\AddtoDoHook{heading/begingroup/part}{\useraggedpart}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addpart{Critique de la critique}
\lipsum[1-8]
\chapter{A chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}


Thank you very much, no blank page after the title indeed and it still starts on an odd page without having to intervene locally.

Not sure part is the good level in this case, but you can prevent page break by deactivate \newpage:
\let\newpage\relax

Make it in a group to limit its scope
\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\addpart{Critique de la critique}
\endgroup

Full example:
\documentclass[12pt, open=any]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\addpart{Critique de la critique}
\endgroup

\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}



Didn't think of that, thank you ! It helps about the skipped page after the part's title, it also disables the automatic begining of the part on the next odd page, but by combining it with a ad hoc function it works just fine.
(To clarify my use of the part level, I need to write a two-page introduction of each part before begining any chapter, and for the said document it is customary not to let any blank page before doing so)

@Hobo_academicus If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider upvoting (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the accepted answer (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

I upvoted it but haven't the required reputation to cast a vote, I hope there's nonetheless a positive impact to it as your answer was indeed helpful, thank you !
